# Iam getting console output as [object HTMLLIElement]

Tags: javascript

```
function render()
    {
       value="";
       b="";

       for(i=0;i<link.length;i++)
        {
          value=document.createElement("li");
          value.innerText=link[i];
          b+=value;
        }  
       console.log(b);
    }
```

I want the output to be li ... li li....li but my output is [object HTMLLIElement] can anyone guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you append `value` to the variable `b`

`value` is [DOM object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

so if you want the string for HTML you can use `outerHTML` property

```
function render()
    {
       value="";
       b="";

       for(i=0;i<link.length;i++)
        {
          value=document.createElement("li");
          value.innerText=link[i];
          b+=value.outerHTML;
        }  
       console.log(b);
    }
```